# Jquery problem: adding something to a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I want to add a string at the end of a jquery object. Something like this:

```
var mytable = $("<table><tbody><tr><td>");
mytable.after("Test</td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

I tried with that too

```
mytable += "Test</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't work that way. When you're dealing with elements in jQuery they are always valid. If it can't validate it, it won't add it. I tried your example and jQuery completed the invalid HTML:

```
var mytable = $("<table><tbody><tr><td>");    
// mytable is equal to $("<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

If you're looking to add a new cell to your table, you could select the required element (i.e. the `tr`) and then use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method

```
mytable.find("tr").append("<td>New cell</td>");
```

Of course, you can add two strings together and put them in a jQuery object as long as they join to make valid HTML

```
var string1 = "<table><tbody><tr><td>First half and";
    string1 = " second half</td></tr></tbody></table>";

mytable = $(string1 + string2);
```

Comment: Ah ok, I think that helps me understand jquery better. I think I know how to fix that now. Thank you and thanks everybody for help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that

```
"<table><tbody><tr><td>" //jQuery will try to create full html elements from what you enter
```

is not valid html nor is

```
"Test</td></tr></tbody></table>" // this will never work, cause this tags are closing only and the table might have been already build when the line before gets executed
```

jQuery might be able to create valid elements from not fully valid html, but this does not work in every case.
I suggest you try to work with valid html!!!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot create page elements unless you provide full valid HTML. I'm not sure of your exact needs but you should do something on this line:

```
var mytable = $("<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>").find("td").text("Test");
```